# how to add in a nested For/Next loop to divvy up file cutting?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple script that utilizes for/next loops to cut files by values in one column `MgrLvl4 = Data(i, 6)` by doing `If Data(i, 1) <> MgrLvl4 Then`
. It cuts everything perfectly, but I have another ask. If I have another element where `MgrLvl4` may split into two categories, how would I implement another for/next loop to get split files?

example: `Mgrlvl4` is in column F and it's Mgr 1. Column G has two values splitting Mgr 1's population. For the sake of ease, we'll just say Column G has half of Mgr 1's pop as Market 1 and the other half as Market 2.

I want to put something like: `If Data(I,6) AND Data(I,7) <> Mgrlvl4 AND Market Then` that will make sure to see `if F2<>F3 & G2<>G3` before starting the next file.

rest of code:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Main()
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim Data, MgrLvl4, Login, Market
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, a As Long
    Dim Dest As Range

    Set Wb = Workbooks("Report_Template.xlsx")

    Set Dest = Wb.Sheets("Population").Range("A2")

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Data = .Range("G2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    Wb.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)

        If Data(i, 6) <> MgrLvl4 Then

            If i > 1 Then

                Dest.Select

                Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                              ValidFileName(Market & " - " & Login & " - " & MgrLvl4 & " - Report.xlsx")
            End If

            With Sheets("Exempt Population")
                .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
            End With

            MgrLvl4 = Data(i, 6)
            Login = Data(i, 3)
            Market = Data(i, 7)

            j = 0
        End If

        a = 0
        For k = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
            Dest.Offset(j, a) = Data(i, k)
            a = a + 1
        Next

        j = j + 1
    Next

    SaveCopy Wb, Market, Login, MgrLvl4                     '<< save the MgrLvl4 report


End Sub

Sub SaveCopy(Wb As Workbook, Market, Login, MgrLvl4)
    Wb.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & _
                  ValidFileName(Market & " - " & Login & " - " & MgrLvl4 & " - Report.xlsx")
End Sub

Private Function ValidFileName(ByVal FName As String, _
                               Optional ByVal ReplaceChar As String = "") As String
    'Return a filename without invalid chars
    'Avoid CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1 to COM9, LPT1 to LPT9 as filename
    Const InvalidChars = "\/:*?""<>|"
    Dim i As Integer, p As Long
    Dim Digit As String
    For i = 1 To Len(InvalidChars)
        Digit = Mid$(InvalidChars, i, 1)
        p = InStr(FName, Digit)
        Do While p > 0
            Mid$(FName, p, 1) = vbNullChar
            p = InStr(FName, Digit)
        Loop
    Next
    For i = 1 To 31
        Digit = Chr$(i)
        p = InStr(FName, Digit)
        Do While p > 0
            Mid$(FName, p, 1) = vbNullChar
            p = InStr(FName, Digit)
        Loop
    Next
    ValidFileName = Replace(FName, vbNullChar, ReplaceChar)
End Function
```

worksheet example of source data: [image: worksheet example of source data:]

[image: splitting files by manager separated by market worksheets]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but `If Data(I,6) AND Data(I,7) <> Mgrlvl4 AND Market Then` isn't valid. Did you mean `If Data(I, 6) <> Mgrlvl4 And Data(I7) <> Market`?

Comment: Did you answer your own question?  `if F2<>F3 & G2<>G3`... just need to make it syntactically appropriate using your array and `and` rather than ampersand.

Comment: @BigBen that may have been what I was looking for, will test on dummy data in the morning and let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but `If Data(I,6) AND Data(I,7) <> Mgrlvl4 AND Market Then` isn't valid.

Maybe you mean `If Data(I, 6) <> Mgrlvl4 And Data(I, 7) <> Market`.

Comment: Hey so I tried it again and realized it wasn't pulling it how I needed. Here's an example. In column A, I have a header row and rows 2-10 are manager 1. Column B has a header and a market 1 for rows 2-5, and market 2 for 6-10. 

I want the script to recognize when markets change within that managers span (so rows 2-5 is one file, rows 6-10 is another file). Then it would move onto the next manager starting in row 11, and so forth

Comment: added screenshot to post

Comment: I realize I could just concatenate the market and manager into a unique key and use my code as-is, but I may need to combine each managers market into it's own worksheet of the manager file, so the way I'm seeking to do it makes more sense

Comment: weird, it started working as I restarted VBE. solved